# pybind: 'ImportError: generic_type: cannot initialize type "": an object with that name is already defined'

Tags: c++, pybind11, class-template

I have a class template `Parameter` that i would like to bind with python accepting different types

This is the code structure

```
// in parameters.h


template<typename T>
class BaseParameter {
  /* ....... */
}

template<typename T>
class Parameter;

// Specifying Derived Parameter types
template<>
class Parameter<double> : public BaseParameter<double> {
    /* ....... */
}

template<>
class Parameter<int> : public BaseParameter<int> {
    /* ....... */
}
```

And binding with pybind

```
// In parameters.cpp


void wrap_double_parameter(py::module& mod) {
    // Trampoline definition
    class PyDoubleParameter : public Parameter<double> 
    {
      public:
         using Parameter::Parameter;
       /* ....... */
     }

    //
    py::class_<Parameter<double>, PyDoubleParameter> PAR(mod, "Parameter");
    PAR
       .def(/* ....... */)
}

void wrap_int_parameter(py::module& mod) {

    class PyIntParameter : public Parameter<int> 
    {
      public:
         using Parameter::Parameter;
      /* ....... */
    }
    //
    py::class_<Parameter<int>, PyIntParameter> PAR(mod, "Parameter");
    PAR
       .def(/* ....... */)
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(parameters, mod) {
    wrap_double_parameter(mod);
    wrap_int_parameter(mod);
}
```

I suspect the problem is that both classes share the name `"Parameter"`. However, that is my intention, in that, in Python I would like a single class `Parameter` that would only accept the specified types. This leads to the error:

```
'ImportError: generic_type: cannot initialize type "Parameter": an object with that name is already defined'
```

Is it possible to bind a single class template with multiple types?

(NOTE: for the sake of brevity i specified the types `int` and `double` however there is also an `Eigen::VectorXd` that would be an accepted type for `Parameter`. Also, I wouldnt want `BaseParameter` to be accesible in Python, hence why i only binded `Parameter`, unless i have to?)

Comment: It looks like you are doing it backwards, py::class_ template parameters should be <derived,base>.

Comment: So `py::class_<PyDoubleParameter, Parameter<double>>`  is that what you mean? However, 
Taking from the example in https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html they write `py::class_<Animal, PyAnimal /* <--- trampoline*/>(m, "Animal");`

Comment: They are doing it the other way around in other places https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#inheritance-and-automatic-downcasting

Comment: "in Python I would like a single class Parameter". Then create a single C++ class and a single pybind binding between it and the Python class. You cannot bind the same Python class to two different C++ classes. It doesn't matter if they are somehow related.